# Flask-MySQL ignore host parameter

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm trying to write a Flask miniapp to connect with a MySQL database. To connect with the database, I use flask-mysql, calling it as this way

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

SECRET_KEY='5f352379324c22463451387a0aec5d2f'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = SECRET_KEY

mydb = MySQL(app, prefix="mydb", host='172.17.0.2', user='testusr', password='test', db='testDB')

(...)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

But, when I run the application, it shows this error

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'testusr'@'%' to database 'testDB'")
```

If I run it from a Docker container, I get a similar error, replacing "%" with "localhost" (in this case, it's not able to connect, due to the database is out of the container)

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")
172.17.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2021 18:00:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I tried to initialize flask-mysql using other this way, with the same error

```
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = '172.17.0.2'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'testusr'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'test'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'testDB'

mydb = MySQL(app)
```

Where can be the error?

Answer (score 1):

Solved changing the connector from flask-mysql to mysql-connector

```
import mysql.connector 

SECRET_KEY='5f352379324c22463451387a0aec5d2f'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = SECRET_KEY

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="172.17.0.2",
  user="testusr",
  password="test",
  database="testDB"
)
```